# Element reference of ViewChild is undefined

Tags: angular, viewchild

Take a look at code below.

```
// ...

  @ViewChild('searchBar', {static: false}) searchBar: IonSearchbar;
  @ViewChild('locations', {static: false}) locationsList: IonList;

// ...

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.searchBarInputSub =
      this.searchBar.ionInput
        .pipe(
          pluck('target', 'value'),
          debounceTime(400),
          distinctUntilChanged()
        ).subscribe(this.onNewLocation);
    console.log(this.locationsList);
  }

  onNewLocation(prefix: string) {
    console.log(this.locationsList);
  }
```

Why `onNewLocation` prints `undefined`? Note that `ngAfterViewInit` prints an object description...

Comment: I don't think you are using the subscription syntax properly. Can you try it using: `).subscribe(() => this.onNewLocation());`

Comment: If I print `prefix` it works.

Comment: @NicholasK You're right. I changed subscription syntax to `.subscribe((location: string) => this.onNewLocation(location));` The problem was the type of `this` pointer inside `OnNewLocation`, it pointed to a subscriber related object.

Comment: @NicholasK Fine :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax is incorrect when you subscribe to the observable, also the `this` in the line `subscribe(this.onNewLocation)` is not referring to what you think it is.

Make the following change:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
   this.searchBarInputSub =
      this.searchBar.ionInput
        .pipe(
          pluck('target', 'value'),
          debounceTime(400),
          distinctUntilChanged()
        )
        .subscribe((location: string) => this.onNewLocation(location));
  }
```